# Example of non-flat $R \subseteq R[w]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, flatness, separable-extension

Let $R \subseteq S$ be two commutative $\mathbb{C}$-algebras such that:

**(1)** $R$ and $S$ are integral domains.

**(2)** $Q(R)=Q(S)$, namely, their fields of fractions are equal.

**(3)** $S=R[w]$, for some $w \in S$.

**(4)** $S$ is [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_algebra) over $R$, namely, $S$ is a projective $S \otimes_R S$-module via $f: S \otimes_R S 
\to S$ given by: $f(s_1 \otimes_R s_2)=s_1s_2$.

> Should such $S$ be flat over $R$? I guess no, so please it would be nice to see a counterexample.

The above is (almost) question 3 of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371948/separability-of-mathbbcx-over-its-mathbbc-subalgebras) question.

Thank you very much!

Now also asked in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372255/example-of-non-flat-r-subseteq-rw).